# How to resize the remaining divs based on the div with large Text in (Created by Template in custom directive)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, dom

Hi I am having a custom directive which has template in which there is a ng-repeat.
This ng-repeat creates DIV's and fills data within these div's
Now problem is I want o resize all the remaining Div's based on the largest height of the DIV.(more text in div more height)
So please help me how to resize/set the height of other divs based on the div with larger height(containing more text)

```js
app.directive("dbsSummry", ["$window","$timeout", "Service",
function ($window,$timeout, Service) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        controllerAs: "data",
        templateUrl: "../RsSummary.html"
        link:function ($scope, element, attrs){
        }
        }
        }
        
        //this directive is used at another places
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.dataInfo[0]" class="row padding-make-vertical ys-padding" style="text-align: left !important;" ng-class="data.bodyCss">
 <span>{{key | titleCase}}</span>
</div>

     <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.dataInfo[1]"  class="row padding-make-vertical ys-padding" class="data.bodyCss">
                            <span>{{value | textCurrency}}</span>
                        </div>
                    

//This is RsSummary.html
```

Comment: post some code of what you did

Comment: yes i have posted the sample code and here i have to set the height of secong ng repeat div's as per the first ng-repeat div's

Answer (score 0):

[

```js
function blockheight(){
var first_block = $(".block1").innerHeight();
$(".block2, .block3").css("height",first_block);
};

$(document).ready(function (){
  blockheight();
});
```

```css
.block1{
  background: red;
}
.block2{
  background: yellow;
}
.block3{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-4">
<div class="block1">
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
Hai
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
<div class="block2">
hai
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
<div class="block3">
hai
</div>
</div>
```

[Div Height will same acording to large content in first div](https://jsfiddle.net/Venkatachalam_Perisetla/1ny5h5xx/)